# How could I remove a jar file after shading it in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, package

I have a package A -> `io.netty`. After maven shading io-netty into A's jar file, using the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <artifactSet>
            <includes>
              <include>io.netty:netty-all:jar:*</include>
            </includes>
          </artifactSet>
          <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>io.netty</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>com.a.io.netty</shadedPattern>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Both A.jar and netty.jar are located in the `target` directory. Is there a way that I can delete `netty-all-*.Final.jar` when running `mvn package`?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but a quick way of performing various housekeeping jobs in different phases of maven build is running ant tasks. Have a look at `maven-antrun-plugin`, if you cannot find a plugin that does exactly what you need

Comment: In this case it's much more simpler to use Maven itself by simply call `mvn clean` that's it.

Comment: Did you manage to get a solution for this?